# User created gesture stored as safety

Tags: android, gesture

I want an the user to have to create a gesture the first time he logs on, then every time thereafter he has to submit that gesture again to enter the app.

I've found several similar things, the only thing is most of the answers here on SO involve using the built in Gesture Builder to create predefined gestures, then associate those with actual activities. I don't want predefined gestures though, I need the user himself to input a gesture the first time he logs in, and then store that.

I might just be misreading this, or thinking too hard about something simple, but if anyone has any insight it would be helpful!

Comment: [Just create the sample Gesture Builder app](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/09/gestures-builder-create-your-gestures.html)  then change the name and package of this app to your own and modify code to be your own.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb, thanks!

Comment: aint no thing. best of luck! :)